# Remove formatting commit from branch before pushing to remote without ugly merge conflicts

Tags: java, git

I'm working on a java project that uses two spaces as indent but I've always used 4 spaces and find it much more readable. I'd like a way to change my code to 4 indents (along w other minor styling changes provided by IntelliJ) while I'm working on it but then discard those changes when I push to remote so that my PR doesn't show that I changed all of the files in the project and the rest of the team can keep their styling. What I've been doing is having an initial formatting commit when I create a new branch, doing my work and making more commits, and then using 'git rebase -i' to delete this initial commit. This works for files that I haven't edited in later commits but if I edit the files, it gives me some messy merge conflicts. Is there a better system to do this?

One other option I looked at was using the ignore blame rev but that doesn't actually change the code, it just changes the blame for the commit (so you can still see the original author) which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: I wonder.. the files that you changed - they use _your_ formatting settings. Do you commit those as is disregarding the team's conventions or do you go into trouble changing the formatting to the one the team prefers?

Comment: BTW, this is where the Tab guys would say "we told you so" :)

Comment: The merge errors happen when I'm rebasing to discard my formatting commit but include the rest of the commits that I've made (the actual changes). So while I'm switching back to my teams formatting.

Comment: I get that. But the real changes - they will use your formatting too. So even though you discard the extra formatting-only-commit, you want the real changes to stay - which formatting are you going to expect for those? Are you going to reformat them manually to follow the team's conventions?

Comment: Yes right now the files w real changes all have merge conflicts after I rebase so I resolve each one manually and reset to the teams format before pushing to remote. Its a pain in the ass but I don't ever push my formatting to remote.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `-X theirs` during rebasing (or merge, or cherry-pick), it'll automatically resolve merge conflicts by choosing the changes you made. So the full syntax:

```
git rebase -i [commit before formatting] -X theirs
```

Then you'll still need to update the files that you actually changed to use the team's conventions.